# ScrollViewDidScroll setTransform and frame height not setting

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, transform

I'm trying to change an imageView's transform and frame in its delegate method.  For some reason, the frame y change sets perfectly but the height adjustment and the transform is not applied.  What is the cause of this?  Here is my code (all of the values are set correctly and all properties are all valid and correct):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    CGFloat offset = [scrollView contentOffset].y + [scrollView contentInset].top;

    CGFloat positionChange = MAX(offset, 0) * 0.7;
    CGFloat heightChange = 0.0;
    if (offset < 0.0) heightChange += -offset;

    [[self coverImageView] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, positionChange)];
    [[self coverImageView] setFrame:CGRectMake([[self coverImageView] frame].origin.x, 64 - positionChange, [[self coverImageView] frame].size.width, 120 + heightChange)];

    NSLog(@"%f %f %f",offset, positionChange, heightChange);

}
```

The position and height change variables are both perfect and change accordingly.  Making sure this method runs on the main thread also doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: Your code is correct. It is in fact transforming both origin.Y and Height of ImageView correctly when you drag the scrollView down.

Comment: I know the code is fine, but it doesn't actually do that.  The Y value shows an adjustment as it scrolls but the height does not change at all on the screen.  Really confused.

Comment: I ran the same code, and it also changes the height.